# I believe because of scope this isnt working the way I would like. Is there a way I can make this work?

Tags: java, scope

```
public char whatsAtPos(BoardPosition pos) {
        char keyChar = ' ';
        for (Map.Entry<Character, List<BoardPosition> > m: board.entrySet() ) {
            //System.out.println(m.getKey() + "," + m.getValue());
            if (m.getValue().contains(pos)){
                System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey());
                keyChar = m.getKey();
            }
        }
        return keyChar;
    }
```

Because of how scope works in java, keyChar never gets changed to m.getKey in that center if statement. It always retains its initialized char of ' '. What can I do to make this work the way I intended? Is it possible?

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with scopes. When `keyChar` doesn't get changed, when either your `for` doesn't iterate or `pos` is in no list.

Comment: @Tom I've done some debugging and the program does enter the if statement. Could this still be the case?

Comment: Can you share output from syso for m.getKey()

Comment: When you already do debugging, then you can also check what `m.getKey()` returns, what `whatsAtPos(...)` returns and how it is treated in the calling method. We don't know anything about your code, so we can't tell you more.

Comment: @www.hybriscx.com I'm getting an output of 'A' from m.getKey(). If that is what you're asking. That is what I'm expecting but it will not return that, even when I make it equal to keyChar and return keyChar

Comment: @Tom I have a print statement inside that if(m.getValue().contains(pos)) that tells me that m.getKey() is equal to 'A'. And from there I make keyChar = m.getKey(); But after this is declared, the value of keyChar is still equal to ' ', like when I initialized it

Comment: When `m.getKey()` return 'A', then `keyChar` should yield that value as well. Since we know nothing else of your code we can't tell you more. It is possible that your `if` will be entered a second time with a different char, it is also possible that the calling method doesn't work the returned `keyChar`. _We_ can only guess. You're the one with the code and the debugger, so you need to dig deeper.

Comment: Also try another default char value, e.g. char keyChar = 'c' and check if it surely remains unchanged.

Comment: Does BoardPosition override equals and hashcode method, if not contains method will always return false.

Comment: @Tom I understand, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is just single output of char, Why don't you break your loop if condition met...?

```
        if (m.getValue().contains(pos)){
            System.out.println("Key: " + m.getKey());
            keyChar = m.getKey(); 
            break;    //Terminate loop
        }
```

Comment: or just return `m.getKey()` no need for variable

Comment: Yeah @CarlosHeuberger